# Tracking Chrome Console Error - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome, google-analytics

When I visit my own WordPress based website sometimes I am seeing the following error message in Chrome console panel.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPwHh.png)

As a result the main CSS file is not loading and the website looks messy. Still I can not find the reason but currently I have a very slow internet connection.

However, I want to know whether this is happening for my website visitors as well.

My question is, is there any solution to log this error message displayed in Chrome console panel using Google Analytics or any other error logging tool so that I can analyse how many visitors are seeing the same error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tools to monitor servers status.
but to install them you need SSH access to your host server - this access is depend on your web-hosting company...
without any more details about your hosting plan i can guess that if you have low and cheap hosting plan - 1 shared CPU and 1 giga RAM - it not good enough for wordpress because wordpress need some moer resources.... and your visitors also see this error somtime - just like you...

Comment: I have SSH access. Any suggested tool to install for tracking remote console errors?

Comment: http://mashable.com/2015/11/17/network-server-tools/#SDrVk9T_OZqj  and also you can choose from here 

https://www.serverdensity.com/monitor/linux/how-to/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but above are for server monitoring tools. What I am looking for is a tool to track browser errors remotely.

Comment: i think you can not know if someone try access to your server -> and fail because connection error. but you can monitor your server load with "htop" or wirh other server side tools. if your CPU is allmost 80% you can be sure that some customer can not connect the server ...